# Inconsistency in search_for Results: Seeking Single fitz.Rect for Entire Phrases in PyMuPDF

Tags: python, pymupdf

I am utilizing the `search_for` function from the `PyMuPDF` library to identify the positions of phrases within a PDF document. Specifically, I am working with this document. ([Link](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/DE/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32022R2379)).

When I search for the phrase `VERORDNUNG (EU) 2022/2379`, the search_for function returns a single `fitz.Rect` representing the entire phrase. However, when searching for `Verordnung (EG) Nr. 617/2008`, the function provides separate `fitz.Rect` instances for each part of the phrase.

My objective is to consistently obtain a single fitz.Rect for the entire phrase. Could someone please explain the reason behind this discrepancy in the function's output?

The code snippet I am using is as follows:

```
import fitz

phrase = "phrase"
path = "path/to/pdf"

with fitz.open(path) as doc:
    page = doc[0]
    text_instances = page.search_for(phrase)
    print(text_instances)
```

Comment: The corresponding issue on the repository has been [answered](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/discussions/3046).